# NLog not using UTF-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, utf-8, configuration, nlog

Since I upgraded NLog to the latest version 5.1.0, logging special characters (e.g. Ö, ä or ß) stopped working. Outout to file is like: Ã¶ Ã¤ Ã¼ for these chars.

I checked the log file with NotePad++ and it says that the encoding is ANSI. However, I have configured NLog to use utf-8. My config:

```
  <target name="logfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/Logs/nLog.csv" archiveAboveSize="50000000" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="3" encoding="utf-8" keepFileOpen="true">
      <layout xsi:type="CsvLayout">
        <column name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
        <column name="level" layout="${level}"/>
        <column name="category" layout="${event-context:item=category}" />
        <column name="message" layout="${message}" />
      </layout>
    </target>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you look the file as UTF-8 (in Notepad++), what do you see? Maybe it is just a wrong guess of Notepad++, or maybe you have two encoding: some lines UTF-8 and some Latin1. note: The character you are showing are very similar to UTF-8 encoding. Save intermediate files, and check the byte values. It may be possible that there is a double encoding.

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ö ä ü'.encode('utf-8').decode('latin1')` returns `Ã¶ Ã¤ Ã¼`. *Another example in PowerShell variant of `.NET`* `[System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 'UTF-8').GetString( [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding( 1252).GetBytes( 'Ã¶ Ã¤ Ã¼'))` -> `ö ä ü`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, I was able to solve the problem. However, I do not know what the real cause of the problem was.

Solution: remove **encoding="utf-8"** from the nLog config AND read the log file as **Encoding.UTF-8** (i.e. when opening the file with a StreamReader).

I don't know why this works since nLog uses UTF-8 as default...